# Downloading solana dev tools error: "curl: (35) schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: Unknown error (0x80092012)"

Tags: curl, solana, certificate-revocation

I am unable to install solana dev tools on windows.

I’m running in the command prompt as administrator:

“curl https://release.solana.com/v1.10.5/solana-install-init-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc.exe --output C:\solana-install-tmp\solana-install-init.exe --create-dirs”

but receive this error:

“curl: (35) schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: Unknown error (0x80092012) - The revocation function was unable to check revocation for the certificate”

I tried to disable revoke by adding --ssl-no-revoke. But then when i want to execute the installer, the file is said to be damaged or unreadable.

solana doc : https://docs.solana.com/cli/install-solana-cli-tools#use-solanas-install-tool

Thanks for your help

Comment: I have a problem to download with curl on windows 7 I get this message (curl: (35) Insufficient randomness), any help ?????

Answer (score 0):

The Windows release artifacts have been bugged for a bit unfortunately, and the last available version is currently 1.9.14, so please update your command to:

```
curl https://release.solana.com/v1.9.14/solana-install-init-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc.exe --output C:\solana-install-tmp\solana-install-init.exe --create-dirs
```

Apologies for the inconvenience!  This should get resolved soon.  In the meantime, you can also switch to WSL if you want to use the 1.10 tools.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this option in your command line : --ssl-no-revoke

Source : https://github.com/TrueCP6/PolyPack/issues/2